# How much more would a DSLR cost with no time limit on video recording?

Tags: dslr, video

Inspired by a [comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34811/how-can-i-record-long-videos-on-my-eos-7d/34813#comment57872_34813) to one of my answers I have a question on my own. We know that one of the reasons for the time limit on video recording in DSLRs is import taxes to the EU. How much more would a DSLR cost if it was imported as a video camera?

Comment: When I bought Sony wx1 the clerk told me it has a 10 minute limit for video, only due to the import tax.

Comment: The best part is the fact that this limit is put on many cameras throughout the world regardless of if the tax is applicable.  My 5D mark 3 in the US also has the 30 minute limit as do many other cameras.  Thanks EU!!!

Comment: and according to this, there is no limit, so it is espeically made for the DK market: http://www.trustedreviews.com/Sony-Cyber-shot-DSC-WX1_Digital-Camera_review_features-table_Page-4#tr-review-summary
hmmm... I wonder if I can firmware upgrade it to not have this limit...

Comment: One of the reasons for this is a 4GB file size limit on FAT32 formatted media.

Comment: The 4GB limit is easily handled in software by starting a new file, there are heaps of software out there that does this. And if I record in SD (not that I would) I still can't get past the 29:59 limit.

Comment: I suspect that even if you could have the software chunk up your files that you'd need some re-engineering of the hardware to improve cooling a bit because you'd have people filming school plays and whatnot and expecting it to work for as long as they've got battery & memory to cope.

Comment: @JamesSnell That's a different issue that might need some tweaking.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I'm voting to close because this seems to just be a question about what the taxes are. I don't see that useful for photography. Further, the question is really only for videography and doesn't apply at all to taking photos.

Comment: This is a question about import tax in the EU, and as such is completely off-topic for a photography site, sorry.

Comment: I disagree that it's off topic, because it highlights why DSLRs are limited to 29:59 when recording video and the actual cost for removing this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

The Danish taxation is:

- 0% on digital cameras for stills.
- 6.7% on accessories, like flash and lenses(!! O.o)
- 12.5% on digital cameras for video

Reference: http://www.toldpriser.dk/toldsatser

Example 5D mrk 3:

In Denmark the price of this nice camera is 4000$.

800$ is VAT, ie. base price is 3200$.

Add 12.5% for being a video camera:  3600$

Add back VAT:  4500$

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on where you import it.

In sweden for example there is 0% customs duty on digital cameras for stills, and 14% on video cameras.

Source: http://www.tullverket.se/innehallao/t/tullochmomsvanligavaror/tullochmomspavanligtforekommandevaror.4.13ca5ad811a0aafa2cc8000927.html

Comment: Could you add a source? Or was it an offline call/conversation with someone?

Comment: @BartArondson: Added the source. Hope it doesn't break the URL length limit in your browser. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked for Norway, and we don't have any import tax for still or video cameras, just a [value added tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added_tax) of 25%.

So if the time limit doesn't make any difference for Norway.

Comment: Could you add a source? Or was it an offline call/conversation with someone?

Comment: I used the "import calculator" http://www.toll.no/templates_TAD/ImportCalc.aspx?id=153564 (in Norwegian).

Comment: You are not in EU :)

Comment: We are not, but we do have a free trade agreement with the EU, and implement more EU laws than any EU country. ;-)