# Canon EOS R recording time

Tags: canon, video, hd-video

I’m looking at buying the Canon EOS R. I’ll want to use it for recording stage shows, which will last longer than 29:59 minutes long.

Is it possible to record on this camera longer than 29:59 in one go? Ideally I’ll need to record up to 1.5 hours at a time.

Do I require a special SD card for this? And does it matter whether I’d want to record in Full HD or 4K?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a limit restriction to the 1080p film video recording time duration on DSLRs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/why-is-there-a-limit-restriction-to-the-1080p-film-video-recording-time-duration)

Comment: Perhaps a dedicated video camera would be better suited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon EOS R have limitation of 29min 59sec for video recording ([source](https://www.canon.bg/pro/stories/eos-r-system-faqs/))

> Another video limitation people comment on is the maximum record time
>   of 29 minutes 59 seconds. This is common in video-capable stills
>   cameras, and it's because of WTO tax rules: any device that records
>   for longer than this is classed as a video camera and taxed at a
>   higher rate.

Depend of framerate and codec you will get those storage limitations:

4k

```
Frame Rates         Codec (H.264)   Recording Time (128 GB Card)    Data Rate
29.97/24/23.98 fps  ALL-I           35 minutes                      480 Mbps
29.97/24/23.98 fps  IPB             2 hours 21 minutes              120 Mbps
```

FullHD

```
Frame Rates         Codec (H.264)   Recording Time (128 GB Card)    Data Rate
29.97/24/23.98 fps  ALL-I           3 hours 6 minutes               90 Mbps
29.97/24/23.98 fps  IPB            23 hours 11 minutes              12 Mbps
```

You can calculate based on your codec and size of videoframe what card do you need.
About the speed of the card you can check [here](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/):
[image]
**NB! speed on the image are in MB, in tables are in Mb** so you need v60 card for 4k and v30 for FullHD